# How to set multiple variables to be used in an ansible task using local commands

Tags: deployment, ansible, ansible-facts

I have a deployment playbook and I want to see some info of the artifact being deployed. For that I created the following task

```
- name: Print application info
  debug:
    msg: "Version to be deployed is {{ app_version }} built on {{ app_build_date }}. Jar md5 is {{ app_md5 }}"
    verbosity: 1
```

What is the best way to define the value of all those variables? The artifact to be deployed is locally accessible in the control node. I don't want to have to create one task to set (register) each variable via the `command` module. I also looked into local facts but IIUC, that means I would need to create another separate play to gather the facts, plus the solution is not self-contained since I would need to manage local files in `/etc/ansible/facts.d` in the control node outside of ansible's control.

Is there a way that is self-contained/managed by ansible?

Comment: Need more information. **What is the command you are running to 'register' the output as variable?** Ideally, the right way to define variables will be to use a key:value format. For example, the object 'app' will have two key:value pairs, version:<version_value> and build_date: <build_date_value>. You access them by app['version'] and app['build_date']. It would still be one variable, "app".

Comment: that's exactly my question: what is the best way to register all those variables? i've done it before for a single variable by doing a `local_action` using the command or shell module, but my question is how to do it en-masse without having to create a task to set each variable individually

Comment: as for the way to actually get each of those values, they each require their own bash command. so i was hoping to combine them to a single script that would extract all the required values in a single invocation

Comment: Yes, now I understood, basically, you either need to execute each 'bash command' in a loop manner, and save output. For example, **loop: "{{ bash_commands}}"** and then, **register: commands_output**. You can access via **commands_output.result[0], commands_output.result[1] etc,** or the second options is, to write a script, that executes the command, parses output into json object. Then execute the script using 'script' module and register the output of scirpt, because you parsed the output to json, your registered output will have information that can be accessed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: ***"What is the best way to define the value of all those variables?"***

A: Create one task to get all values. Make the commands return the values *`['version', 'date', 'md5']`* each on a separate line, register the result, and create a dictionary. For example, declare the variable

```yaml
  app: "{{ dict(['version', 'date', 'md5']|
                zip(result.stdout_lines|map('trim'))) }}"
```

Display the attributes

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "Version {{ app.version }} date {{ app.date }} md5 {{ app.md5 }}"
```

See the filters [zip and dict](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-items-from-multiple-lists-zip-and-zip-longest).

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    app: "{{ dict(['version', 'date', 'md5']|
                  zip(result.stdout_lines|map('trim'))) }}"

  tasks:

    - shell:
        cmd: |
          pkg info gtar | grep Version | cut -d : -f 2-
          pkg info gtar | grep Installed | cut -d : -f 2-
          md5 /usr/local/bin/gtar | cut -d = -f 2
      register: result

    - debug:
        var: app
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -l test_11,test_13

PLAY [all] ************************************************************************************

TASK [shell] **********************************************************************************
changed: [test_13]
changed: [test_11]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  app:
    date: Mon Jan 24 08:11:24 2022 UTC
    md5: 25d822c014c4acea21dc2df359cb13b1
    version: '1.34'
ok: [test_13] => 
  app:
    date: Mon Jan 24 06:08:14 2022 UTC
    md5: 25d822c014c4acea21dc2df359cb13b1
    version: '1.34'

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
test_11: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_13: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```